# Помогите исправить функцию

Tags: javascript

Суть функции заключается в том, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку переводить элементы по **Id**, но после нажатия функция срабатывает только на одном элементе. Подскажите что можно сделать?

```
function connectValue(btnId, elemId, txt) { 
document.getElementById(btnId).onclick = function () {
document.getElementById(elemId).lastChild.nodeValue = txt;  
};
}

connectValue("ru", "1", "ГЛАВНАЯ");
connectValue("en", "1", "HOME");

connectValue("ru", "2", "КОНТАКТЫ");
connectValue("en", "2", "CONTACTS");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что вы используете `.onclick`, и при каждом вызове `connectValue` свойство `.onclick`, которое хранит обработчик события, перезаписывается. 
Если вам нужно добавить несколько обработчиков используйте `addEventListener`. Тут [подробная](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) документация.

```js
function connectValue(btnId, elemId, txt) { 
  document.getElementById(btnId).addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById(elemId).lastChild.nodeValue = txt;  
  });
}

connectValue("ru", "1", "ГЛАВНАЯ");
connectValue("en", "1", "HOME");

connectValue("ru", "2", "КОНТАКТЫ");
connectValue("en", "2", "CONTACTS");
```

```html
<div id="1">ГЛАВНАЯ</div>
<div id="2">КОНТАКТЫ</div>

<button id="ru">RU</button>
<button id="en">EN</button>
```

Comment: Благодарю, всё заработало! Ещё один маленький вопрос, возможно ли изменения которые произошли после нажатия на кнопку записать за пользователем, в cookie или localStorage?

Comment: @DannyWalker Вы хотите вести лог действий пользователя ?

Comment: Хотел бы чтобы запоминался перевод за пользователем, после его нажатия на кнопку, и закрытия вкладки

Comment: Можно добавить в обработчик клика `localStorage.setItem('lang', btnId);
`, но тогда в localStorage запись будет происходить несколько раз и лучше будет если вы модифицируете код так что бы на кнопке был 1 event listener в котором модифицировались все элементы.

Comment: Хорошо я почитаю про это подробнее, ещё раз спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Надо давать обработчик события через `addEventListener('click', function () {` потому что `onclick` это всего лишь свойство объекта, которое вы перезаписываете.

```
function connectValue(btnId, elemId, txt) { 
  document.getElementById(btnId).addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById(elemId).lastChild.nodeValue = txt;  
  });
}

connectValue("ru", "1", "ГЛАВНАЯ");
connectValue("en", "1", "HOME");

connectValue("ru", "2", "КОНТАКТЫ");
connectValue("en", "2", "CONTACTS");
```

Comment: "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",